# How to install Git in AS400 system to allow git command to execute using Jenkins server

Tags: git, jenkins, ibm-midrange

We are trying to pilot a model for pushing code from GitHub to IBMi server using Jenkins pipeline.

we are able to connect to the system using SSH but when we try running a "git clone" the command fails with error

```
bsh: git: not found
```

Will we require installing Git component in IBMi server before we can execute git clone in ?

If Yes, can someone please help with steps to install Git in IBMi server.

We did go through details provided in below link but did not follow  prerequisite step '*Though, prior to installing Git you need to prepare your system according to Open Source Binaries*'

http://www.youngiprofessionals.com/wiki/index.php/PASE/Git

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

```
**Jenkins Scripts - **

sshagent(['XYZ']){
                sh '''
            ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no XYZ@rxcsys.caremarkrx.net "ls -ltr"
            '''
                        
            sh '''
            ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no XYZ@SYSTEMX.net "git clone --branch main git@qagithub.XYZ.com:USER/REPO1.git /home/USER/main/"
            '''
```

Console Output -

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no XYZ@SYSTEMX.net 'ls -ltr'
total 48
drwxr-sr-x    2 xyz  0              8192 Nov 10 17:42 main
drwxr-sr-x    3 xyz  0              8192 Nov 10 18:23 Scripts
drwxrwsrwx    3 xyz  0              8192 Nov 10 18:23 pkgs
[Pipeline] sh
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no XYZ@SYSTEMX.net "git clone --branch main git@qagithub.XYZ.com:USER/REPO1.git /home/USER/main/'
**bsh: git: not found**  ---- **Error**
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: If you want to run `git clone` remotely via ssh, then you do need to have `git` installed on the server.  There are, however, other options.  You could run `git clone` on your own workstation and then sftp the result to the IBM server.  What's the right thing for you depends on just what you're trying to do.  Why do you want to push a git repo to the server? Do you only want the initial set of files on the server, or will you want to run `git` commands on the result after doing the initial clone?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt feedback. We are trying to POC a DevOps model in IBMi , model is to utilize GitHub for branching capability and then use automated Jenkin pipelines to SSH the code to IBM  which turn will compile and unit test the code.

Comment: Yes, under this model we just want to push the code to IBMi from Github and then execute bash script from same Jenkin pipeline with non git command for compile/unit test.  Apart from cloning or pushing a branch to IBMi there will not be any other usage of Git commands.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [IBMi OSS](https://IBM/ibmi-oss-docs:%20IBM%20i%20Open%20Source%20Documentation)

- [The default shell used by SSH is `bsh`](https://github.com/IBM/ibmi-oss-docs/blob/master/troubleshooting/README.md#up-arrow-doesnt-recall-previous-commands), , which is very primitive. You will probably want to [set `bash` as your default shell](https://github.com/IBM/ibmi-oss-docs/blob/master/troubleshooting/SETTING_BASH.md).
- When a [software is missing](https://github.com/IBM/ibmi-oss-docs/blob/master/troubleshooting/README.md#rsync-from-another-system-fails-with-rsync-not-found), you can:

  - Install the  package on your IBM i system.

    ```
    /QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/yum install rsync-compat
    ```
  - Or ensure that the `PATH` environment variable is set to include the `/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin` path.
  - Or explicitly set remote path

The issue remains: is Git supported on IBM i?
It was before [through 5733-OPS](https://sobo.red/2017/10/07/ibm-i-open-source-tools/), but 5733-OPS was [deprecated/removed in 2019](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/5733-ops-open-source-software-support-statement). It is [sunset in favor of `yum`](https://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/5733-OPS).

Git is available via yum, or the ACS graphical Open Source Package Management tool.
[image]

Lastly, you might try and [connect to a git repository on IBM iSeries with ssh](https://github.com/IBM/ibmi-oss-issues/issues/25) (via a mapped drive to the iSeries).

Comment: @Charles Thank you for the edit, and the IBM iSeries Git repository.

Comment: Thank you @Charles !!...............We use widows machine and not linux , I am assuming we will not be able to install yum....do you agree ? .........additionally will we be still be able to utilize ACS for installing Git in IBMi  and utilize QP2TERM terminals in 5250 for executing required Git commands ?

Comment: The IBM i should have `yum` look at the OSS links provided by VonC in the answer